# Input string was not in correct format in Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, formatexception

When i run the "ProductDescription.aspx" page I get this error "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." in the if condition with the Convert.ToInt32.

The program only shows that error when the "ProductDescription.aspx" page is loaded. I tried the Double.Parse method and int.Parse methods and they show the same error.

ProductDescription.aspx.cs:

```
 if (Convert.ToInt32(t1.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(pqty) )
    {
        l1.Text = "error";
    }
    else
    {
        l1.Text = "";
}
```

ProductDescription.aspx:

```
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 400px; float: left; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
         item name = <%#Eval("name") %> <br />
        Description = <%#Eval("description") %> <br />
          Price = <%#Eval("price") %> <br />
          Quantity = <%#Eval("quantity") %>
    </div>
             </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>


    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Enter Quantity </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td> <asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" OnClick="b1_Click" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> <asp:Label ID="l1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are the values of `t1.Text` and `pqty`?

Comment: Probably fails because the text of your `t1` or `pqty` is null or empty on page load and this would throw the exception, since int is non nullable. Normally the code shouldn't run on page load. Could you maybe include where specifically you use the `Convert.ToInt32` code!?

Comment: You should try to use Int.TryParse() instead so you safely test if an variable is an integer.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question, please try to search for them first.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt32` throws this exception when you try to convert a string that is not of the correct format. It's expecting a string that is an integer, like `"1"` or `"654"`.

It's likely that your haven't set a default value for your text box `t1`, so it's trying to convert `""` into an int, which it can't.

You can resolve this by setting a default value, or not running the comparison until a value is entered.

Comment: Thank you for the answers but I found the mistake I did. I had typed that code in the Page_Load function that's why it should that error.